# What is the exact element of clear button at IOS datepicker?

Tags: java, ios, gwt

I have an input element which type is "date" with specified default value. Using Safari when user clicks inside this input element - popup shows up and allows to change a date. There is a clear button on a top of this popup. When click on this clear button - the value is set to default (but expected result of value is ""). How can I identify exactly "clear" button element or how can I catch this event when user clicks on "clear" button at datepicker popup in Safari? Thanks

Comment: Please, show us your code. Provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want to remove the clear button or intercept the event?

Comment: To intercept the event should be enough